# What's the smallest lossless video codec supported by ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I recorded some 2k 60fps videos with libx264rgb losslessly using the `ultrafast` preset. They are about 3GB/min. Re-encoding libx264rgb with the `veryslow` preset only reduces it to 1.6GB/min. Is there a better codec? Encoding time doesn't really matter as I can run it overnight.

Comment: This largely depends on *which content* you have: (photorealistic, CG, how many motion and so on). Try all of them: h264 lossless, ffv1, lagarith, etc, and decide which one works better for you.

Comment: https://forum.doom9.org/forumdisplay.php?f=54